# Error in Convolutional Neural network for input shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have 1000, 28*28 resolution images. I converted those 1000 images into numpy array and formed a new array with size of (1000,28,28). So, while
 creating convolution layer using keras, input shape(X value) is specified as (1000,28,28) and output shape(Y value) as (1000,10). Because I ha
ve 1000 examples are inputs and 10 categories of output.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal',input_shape=(1000,28,28)))
.
.
.
model.fit(train_x,train_y,batch_size=32,epochs=10,verbose=1)
```

So, while using `fit` function, it shows `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 28, 28)` as error. Pls help me guys to provide proper input and output dimension for CNN.

Code:

```
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal',input_shape=(4132,28,28)))
 model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
 model.add(Dropout(0.25))

 model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
 model.add(Dropout(0.25))

 model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dropout(0.4))

 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dropout(0.3))
 model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

 model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])
 model.summary()

 train_x  = numpy.array([train_x])

 model.fit(train_x,train_y,batch_size=32,epochs=10,verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the inputs to 4 dimensions with `channel` set to `1` : (1000, 28, 28, 1) and you need to change the `input_shape` of the convolutional layer to `(28, 28, 1)`:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),...,input_shape=(28,28,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your numpy arrays need a fourth dimension, the common standard is to number the samples with the first dimension, so changing (1000, 28, 28) to (1, 1000, 28, 28).

You can read more about this [here](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/).

Comment: If I convert (1000,28,28) to (1,1000,28,28) then `ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 1000  target samples.` is occuring

Comment: You'd need to change your input shape to have a single sample. I can't tell much more without seeing the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

from your input it looks like you are using tensorflow as back end.

In keras the `input_shape` should always be 3 dimension .
For tensorflow as a backend the `input_shape` to your model will be

```
input_shape = [img_height,img_width,channels(depth)]
```

in your case for tensor flow backend that should be

```
input_shape = [28,28,1]
```

and the shape of `train_x` should be

```
train_x = [batch_size,img_height,img_width,channels(depth)]
```

in your case

```
train_x = [1000,28,28,1]
```

As you are using a gray scale image,the dimension of the image will be (image_height, image_width) and hence you have to add an extra dimension to the image which will result to (image_height, image_width, 1) the '1' suggests the depth of the image,for gray scale that is  '1' and for rgb that is '3'.